# Why does my very, very simple sort function return an unsorted list

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, sorting

If I do:

```
var my_list = ["g", "be", "d", "f", "hu", "i", "jc", "lu", "ma", "mi", "w"];
var sorted_list = my_list.sort(function(a,b) {
                        return a > b;
                       });
console.log(sorted_list);
```

I get:

```
["i", "g", "d", "f", "be", "hu", "jc", "lu", "ma", "mi", "w"]
```

(And if I try try it again I get a different unsorted result).

But when I do this:

```
var my_list = ["g", "be", "d", "f", "hu", "i", "jc", "lu", "ma", "mi", "w"];
var sorted_list = my_list.sort();
console.log(sorted_list);
```

I get the correct sorted result:

```
["be", "d", "f", "g", "hu", "i", "jc", "lu", "ma", "mi", "w"]
```

What is wrong with the function I'm providing to sort?

I can't use sort without a function because in my real code, I'm trying to sort objects. If this can't work, is there another way I can sort my objects by a certain attribute?

Answer (score 5):

Comparison functions should return a value of -1, 0 or 1 depending on how the operands compare.

If you only perform an equality check (yielding 0 or 1) the sort result will be undefined, because the internal sort algorithm is inherently unstable.

This would be an equivalent of the standard sort:

```
if (a == b) {
    return 0;
} else if (a < b) {
    return -1;
} else { // a > b
    return 1;
}
```

The above is not extremely useful, but merely serves to illustrate which comparison elements should be present.

Comment: Why mix if/else with the conditional operator?

Comment: @Bergi Well, fair enough, it's just for illustrative purposes anyway, but personally I have no trouble reading either variant :)

Answer (score 3):

Comparison function should return a number not a boolean. Alternatively you can use [String.prototype.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method which is designed exactly for this purpose:

```
var sorted_list = my_list.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

> The localeCompare() method returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order.